# How to model "One or Many" relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

I have a model `Owner`. The `Owner` has a type which can be either `Individual` or `Business`. Based on type, the `Owner` may have One-to-One or One-to-Many relationship with `Property` model. If `Individual`, it can only have one `Property` but if it's `Business`, it may have many `Property`s. How do you model this in Django? How can I enforce the `Individual` to have only one `Property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating the Property model with a ForeignKey to Owner and then add some custom validation by overriding the save function of the class as such.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class Property(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.owner.type == "Individual":
            if Property.objects.filter(owner=self.owner).exists():
                raise IntegrityError
        super(Property, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This won't cover all cases such as manually adding records to the database or using certain django methods that bypass the save functionality but it will cover a majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PostgreSQL or SQLite you can enforce this with a partial unique index. As of Django 2.2 you can do this [declaratively](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint), something like:

```
from django.db.models import Model, Q, UniqueConstraint

class Property(Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        constraints = [UniqueConstraint(fields=["owner"], condition=Q(type="Individual"))]
```

Before Django 2.2 you can do this with a migration. Something like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [ ... ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX property_owner 
                           ON property(owner_id) 
                           WHERE type = 'Individual'"),
    ]
```

Comment: Nice!  I wish I could use this for MySQL.  I really need to get away from MySQL and move to PostgreSQL :/